# How to send message to a server through socket in 'C' when server is started after the client?

Tags: c, sockets, vb6, client-server

I have made a client (in C) which is trying to connect to a server (in VB 6.0) till the connection is established. If the server is ready t listen and then we run the client program trying to connect and send a message, it works fine and also the response is received on the client side.
But when we start the client program before server, it tries to connect after a short interval to the server until it gets connected (in an infinite loop). When we switch on the server, the client connects successfully to the server but doesn't send the message. I am not able to find the problem in this case.
I have checked in the 'wireshark' that client doesn't send any message.

How come the program works fine when the server is running before the client and not in the other case?

Please suggest how to find the problem.
Here is the code for the client program:

```
int
tcp_send()
{
    int sd, newSd, rc, i, cliSd, servLen, num, k, p;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    struct hostent *h;
    char si[4];
    char line[MAX_MSG];
    char message[MAX_MSG];
    struct  timeval tp;
    time_t now;
    char msg[MAX_MSG];  
    char str[MAX_MSG];

    strcpy(msg, "Hello World");

    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("111.1.1.11");
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    /* create socket */
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sd<0) 
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    rc = -1;    
    for (;rc!=0;)
    {
        /* connect to server */
        rc = connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
        if(rc<0) 
        {
            sleep(2);
        }

    }

    memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
    memset(si, 0, sizeof(si));
    num = strlen(msg);
    integertostring(si, num, 4);
    memcpy(message, si, 4);
    memcpy(message + strlen(message), msg, strlen(msg));

    rc = send(sd, message, strlen(message), 0);
    if(rc<0)
    {
      close(sd);
      exit(1);

    }

    sleep(1);
    read_line(sd,line);
    memset(line,0x0,MAX_MSG);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: We can't tell anything without seeing your code.

Comment: Debug maybe? What's the return value of `send(sd, message, strlen(message), 0)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to `close` the socket after `connect` has failed and recreate it again.